# Doctrine-PHPCR-ODM Event doesn't fire

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-cmf, doctrine-phpcr

I have a doctrine-phpcr-odm document named article,I want to slugify a field before updating each article.
The event fires for doctrine-orm entities but dosn't fire for doctrine-phpcr-odm documents!

```
class ArticlePreUpdateListener
{
    public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        var_dump($args);
    }
}

article.pre_update.listener:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\ArticlePreUpdateListener
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preUpdate}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/bundles/phpcr_odm/events.html),  Doctrine-PHPCR-ODM events works the same way as for Doctrine ORM events. The only differences are:

- use the tag name doctrine_phpcr.event_listener resp.
  `doctrine_phpcr.event_subscriber` instead of `doctrine.event_listener;`
- expect the argument to be of class
  `Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs`.

Comment: does that mean you solved your question? or does it not work with the doctrine_phpcr.event_subscriber tag? (note you can add both tags if its the same behaviour for both)

Comment: @dbu Yes using doctrine_phpcr.event_subscriber tag Solved the problem.tnx

Answer (score -1):

```
`/** 
  * @Document 
  */
class Article
{
    [...]

    /**
     * @PreUpdate
     * @PrePersist
     */
    public function slugifiyField()
    {
       $this->yourField = yourSlugifyFunction($this->yourField);
    }
}
```

Then, add a function with a `preUpdate` annotation (I've added `PrePersist` to slugify when article is created too)

Edit : According to your comment, I removed `HasLifeCycleCallback` annotation, but it looks you can use `Pre/PostUpdate` annotations directly within document entity.

Comment: Contrary to the ORM, PHPCR-ODM does not use the `@HasLifecycleCallbacks` marker(http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-phpcr-odm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-callbacks).

Comment: Sorry, I based my response on http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#haslifecyclecallbacks I edited my answer